# Force page content to be 100% of view port

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I just can't get it right! The content section should expand to 100% of the view port (minus the header/footer)!  If the content is small I like to see the header at the top, the footer at the bottom of the window view, and then the content fill the rest of the area between the header and the footer.  Can someone please give me the magic CSS to do this?  I've looked in so many SO posts about this topic and cannot get it to work for whatever reason.  I don't think the browser matters but I've tried, at least, the latest Chrome and IE 11.

If you happen to be an angularjs expert another issue I have is the following: if the content angular will add to the DOM is way bigger than the original template and flows pass the viewable window area then I see a quick flicker on the page. It seems to first display the template in its original size and then when angular does its thing it pushes the size of the content area down pass the viewable window area but there's a small annoying flicker there.  This has nothing to do with the displaying of the binding expressions as I already cover that with ngCloak.

All and any comment is appreciated in advanced!

The following demo code is at JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZuAjg/7/

HTML:

```
<div id="body_wrapper">
    <div>
        <div id="header">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content_wrapper">
            <div id="content">INHALT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#body_wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
#header {
    background-color: orange;
    height:100px;
}
#content_wrapper {
    background-color: limegreen;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
#footer {
    background-color: silver;
    height:1.5em;
    width:800px;
    margin: -1.5em auto;
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into box-sizing: border-box; It will do what you need it too.

HTML:

```
<div id="body_wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content_wrapper">
        <div id="content">INHALT</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#body_wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:lightblue;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;

}
#header {
    background-color: orange;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
#content_wrapper {
    background-color: limegreen;
    height:100%;
}
#footer {
    background-color: silver;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/8zQCq/

Comment: Thanks Mathew, your suggestions made a difference!  However, I missed a DIV there that I use to control a shell around the content (see the ID=content_window) in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/webteckie/8zQCq/1/

Can see if you can make the content_window cover the full area down to the fixed header at the bottom of the viewable area?

Thanks!

Comment: Never mind the fiddle in the last comment.  I need to do a better job at it to demo my issue.  But, in any case, it is definitely better now!  Will post a new fiddle if I can get to duplicate my other issue.